# Java: link object to a variable in another object

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

This is a bit difficult to explain so I wrote up and example to illustrate the concept. In the following example I have a stock class which models the figures that affect a stock simulation program. I also have a MarketModifier class which represents events which would affect the stocks in different ways.

```
public class ExampleArea  
{
    public static void main(String cvhfg[]) 
    {  
        Stock test = new Stock(1f,1f,1f,1f);
        MarketModifier worldEvent = 
            new MarketModifier("Bad publicity",-2.5f,"publicOpinion");
    }   
}
class MarketModifier
{
    public MarketModifier(String name, float modifier, String variable) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        Modifier = modifier;
        this.variable = variable;
    }
    String name;
    float Modifier;
    String variable;
}
class Stock
{
    public Stock(float value, float integrity, float publicPresence, float publicOpinion) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.integrity = integrity;
        this.publicPresence = publicPresence;
        this.publicOpinion = publicOpinion;
    }
    float value;
    float integrity;
    float publicPresence;
    float publicOpinion;
    //...other variables...
}
```

My question is how would I link the marketModifer to the variable in the Stock model (in the example above it is "publicOpinion" set in the "variable" String) without using a string. Strings have the problem of possibly mistyping them, and I would need a switch to identify which variable the modifier was affecting.

I thought of using an enum but I would still need a switch table to check them and I would also have to update the enum values every time a stock has a different variable which could be affected (there could be additional variables in the subclasses of Stock). The other option I thought of was reflection but this solution, though I think it would work, seems overly complicated, and adds more difficulty in reading than it solves.

So again, is there a better way to link the an object to the variable(s) that it affects in another object (maybe some kind of observer/watcher pattern?).

Comment: So you want the `variable` property to be the name of the modified property on Stock??

Comment: I want it to be compile time verified that there is that variable in Stock (the string is not compile time checked). In c++ or C# I could accomplish this with some kind of pointer to the variable that it affects. But Java has no pointers, how would I do this better than the string implementation above?

Comment: I can't understand why you don't want to use enums.

Comment: If I use enums I have to update it for each variable that is added to Stock or its subclasses. This is a library so the people using it will have to know to go in a update the enum (not vary adaptable for libraries). Plus I would really like to avoid:  
switch(variable){   
case value: //...  
case integrity: //...  
case publicOpinion: //...  
} (how do you add code here?)

Comment: @J.Pichardo I think that OP wants to update the value of the field name specified in the variable string. I think he is looking for a reflective approach...

Comment: @Jay Yeah I thinks the same, but he said no reflexión

Comment: @J.Pichardo I had a similar issue once. Solved it by implementing listeners... He can create different listeners that would be able to update the values in the way he wants. Like this: `MarketModifier worldEvent = new MarketModufier("Bad Product", -2.25f, Stock.PUBLIC_OPINION_MODIFER);`. You getting my point?

Comment: @Jay, yeah I understand, in fact I like it

Comment: @J.Pichardo So let me implement this real quick and upload to my public repo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to avoid reflective approaches, what I can suggest is to use an *event listener* approach.

So what you basically want to do is to listen for the event when market action is performed and then modify the values in your `Stock` object.

So you would need an interface like this that your `MarketModifier` would invoke when it is processed.

**Modifier.java**

```
public interface Modifier {    
    public void modify(Stock taget, float modifier);    
}
```

And this interface's implementations would be able to modify any value(s) in the stock object.

An implementation would look like this:

**PublicOpinionModifier.java**

```
public class PublicOpinionModifier implements Modifier {

    public void modify(Stock target, float modifier) {
        target.setPublicOpinion(target.getPublicOpinion() + modifier);  
    }

}
```

After that, you can create your `MarketManager` class like this:

**MarketManager.java**

```
public class MarketManager {

    // The name of the event.
    private String name = "unkown";

    // Modifier value of the event.
    private float modifier = 0f;

    // The listener to listen for the modifications.
    private Modifier modificationListener;

    // The target stock object towards which the action is directed.
    private Stock target;

    /**
     * Executes the market event.
     */
    public void executeAction() {
        modificationListener.modify(target, modifier);
    }

}
```

The `MarketManager` would have the target object (the `Stock` object to update) and an implementation of `Modifer` which would be acting as a listener which would be invoked when the market stuff is going on...

**TestMarket.java**

```
public class TestMarket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stock stock = new Stock(1f, 3f, 1f, 3f);

        MarketManager manager = new MarketManager();
        manager.setTarget(stock);
        manager.setName("Bad Publicity");
        manager.setModifier(-2f);
        manager.setModificationListener(new PublicOpinionModifier());

        manager.executeAction();
    }

}
```

Neat!

---

I have uploaded a more clean and elaborated version in my [public repo](https://github.com/JExaples/quicklooks/tree/master/market-manager-app).